# how to close ticket using servicenow api in automation anywhere

Tags: servicenow, automationanywhere, servicenow-rest-api

How to close the task using Service Now Rest API in automation anywhere?
I need to close the ticket using RestAPI could you please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Using the REST API Explorer, select **Modify a record  (PUT)**, table name **incident**, and the **sys_id** of the ticket.

The body needs 3 fields:

```
{
  "state":"7",
  "close_code":"Closed/Resolved by Caller",
  "close_notes":"blabla"
}
```

**close_code** (also called *Resolution code* in the UI) is mandatory. For the admissible values, in the UI navigate to **System Definition / Choice Lists**, and search for table incident, element close_code.

**close_notes** (also called *Resolution notes* in the UI) is mandatory, but it's free text.

**state** is either 6 for *Resolved*, or 7 for *Closed*.

Answer (score 1):

After scouring the forums and trying different solutions I was finally able to successfully close the issue ticket by using a patch request with these parameters.
Using the Table api endpoint for the UTAH release,

```
https://<instance>.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/incident/{incident_id}'
```

```
    resolve = \
        {
            "close_code": "Closed/Resolved By Caller",
            "incident_state": "7",
            "caller_id": "admin",
            "close_notes": "Closed by API"
        }
```